# Notation question: Does $\inf$ require a subscript?

Tags: sequences-and-series, notation, supremum-and-infimum

I am wondering which is more acceptable notation to use.

If I am trying to denote the infimum of the set of numbers $\{\alpha_m:m\geq k, m,k \in \mathbb {N}\}$, which is more acceptable to write?

$$\inf\{\alpha_m:m\geq k, m,k \in \mathbb {N}\}$$
OR
$$\inf_{m\geq k}\{\alpha_m:m,k \in \mathbb {N}\}$$

Or in summary, does the $\inf$ notation require a subscript?

Comment: inf is a function whose input is a set, and whose output is a real number. Thus, the first notation is the natural choice.

Comment: I would write $\inf\{\alpha_m:m\in\Bbb N,m\ge k\}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both notations are bad. Indeed, the condition $k \in \mathbb{N}$ is not relevant (and even misleading) inside the set $\{\alpha_m:m\geq k, m,k \in \mathbb {N}\}$. You could write instead:

> For each $k \in \mathbb {N}$, let $x_k = \inf \{\alpha_m \mid m\geqslant k
>  \}$. Or, let  $E_k = \{\alpha_m \mid m\geqslant k\}$ and let $x_k = \inf E_k$.